# Differential geometry and the requirement for the existence of a tangent line at every point

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry

In do Carmo’s book “Differential Geometry of Curves and Surfaces” he mentions in passing (pp. 5-6) that “[for] the study of the differential geometry of a curve it is essential that there exists a tangent line at every point.” I understand that from an intuitive level we cannot have a particle trace where at one point the speed is zero. But is there a more fundamental theoretical reason for this requirement? Perhaps the reason has more to do with topology…

Comment: Actually, in differential geometry one also frequently studies piecewise-smooth curves.